# Get total hours/minutes/seconds iPad can record video

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to retrieve how long can the iPad record a video before becoming full. Is there a way on how to get this information?

Comment: you can record n minutes and check file size, then calculate average size of 1 minute... I guess you got my idea. But size of file may slightly vary in depends of pictures

Comment: Have you done some research on the video bitrate of iPad? My answer would boil down to `bytes_of_space_available*8 / video_bitrate`.

Comment: I'm using GPUImage to record video. bytes_of_space_available you are referring to the mb or gb remaining space right?

Comment: @Dreyfus15 No, literally what I wrote: The number of _bytes_ of storage remaining on the disk.